# jsdocs export const { arrow function }

Tags: jsdoc

I'm a bit new to jsdocs, and I'm trying to properly document arrow functions.

Everything is fine until I add "export" at the beginning of the line, I saw multiple answers that recommended to add `@module` at the top and `@memeberof` in the documentation, but these options don't seem to work for me.

This is a sample of my code:

```
/** @module SampleModule */

/**
 * Function description
 *
 * @param {string} _type - Component type.
 * @param {string} currentName - Current component's name.
 * @param {string} canonicalname - Current site.
 * @returns {undefined}
 * 
 * @example
 * 
 *  activateComponentWizard('t1', 'test 1', 'www.example.com')
 */

export const activateComponentWizard = async (_type, currentName, canonicalname) => { ... }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Any ideas what am I missing?